# Storing data Internally vs. Externally in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a 2D game in Java that will involve monsters.  I am wondering if it makes more sense to have a Monster class that has its data populated by an outside text file after it is instantiated(that way I can easily add more monsters), or rather does it make more sense to have a Monster super class and then have sub classes that extend said Monster class?

**External on Left, Internal on Right**

[image: External on Left, Internal on Right]

If all the monsters do the same thing, then I see why just creating the monster from external data would be beneficial, but would that limit me in other parts of the game?

I couldn't find this question anywhere else... seems like a common scenario when planning out how to code a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using a single class and generating the different monster instance from data contained in a file is much better.

Why are you afraid that's going to limit you? You can always extend the data you generate the monsters from and to describe all the attributes and behaviour you need.

Conversely, if you have a class for every possible monster you're going to have in the game you'll have a huge number of classes with the net result of littering your codebase without getting any benefit.

Eric Lippert has a [series of blog posts](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) where he discuss very similar design decisions. You might find it interesting.

Comment: Yes I think this is the better option as well.  It avoids having many similar classes, and allows the values to be easily changed without needing to recompile the program.

Comment: That link does appear to be useful, so thank you.  I suppose I was worried I might run into nullpointer exceptions if the monsters aren't predefined in the game when they are interacting with other objects, but as you pointed out I can extend that data I generate from the monsters...

Very useful insight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should make an abstract class Monster which will be extended afterwards with any other class that you need.

```
public abstract class Monster() {}

public class Predator extends Monster() {}
public class Alien extends Monster() {}
```

See more at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: I prefer this as well.  Granted you'll probably end up with more lines of code, but for me it's more organized, and allows people to simply extend your Monster class to create their own.